# Failed to load resources (draco, basis)

Tags: javascript, webpack, basis

I've been struggling issue with draco and basis loader.

I'm using webpack to build my project, and it's `npm run build` configuration looks like this:

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const commonConfiguration = require('./webpack.common.js')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(
    commonConfiguration,
    {
        mode: 'production',
        plugins:
        [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin()
        ]
    }
)
```

Everything is fine, I'm using Live Server VSCode extension, but my resources aren't loading since this error:
[image]

The problem is, I have those in source project folder and also I had put it in my dist folder created by webpack to make sure it's not path fault. Well, it's not.[image]

Neither of those are working. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve the issue. Remember to put whole path to folder where encoder/transcoder is placed. My problem was that I declaired the basis in the folder `/basis/`, what is working in dev mode, but in production mode I had to declaire it as `./basis/`.